# Gene networks in insects

Tags: gene, network

I am working on gene networks and I currently have the [honey bee gene network](https://price.systemsbiology.org/research/honeybee-transcriptional-regulatory-network/) to work with. What I am missing is a gene network that I could compare it with. Could you please guide me to a database/website that I could use to download a gene network and use for my study. I am looking for gene networks from closely related species (hopefully another honey bee gene species (other than *Apis mellifera* or a hymenopteron. I am open to all flying insect species really. Kindly advice.

Comment: I am not sure what a gene network is (in so far as it is hypothetical concept) but the kind of data you have for honeybee must exist for the insect to end all genetic insects. Have you looked?

Comment: Not closely related but Drosophila is well-annotated: http://www.droidb.org/DBdescription.jsp. Unfortunately interaction networks are most likely to be found in model species, of which there are not many. Some work on wasps seems to have been done by Amy Toth (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=kzt2orQAAAAJ&hl=en) and by others (https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12915-016-0285-y) but they are not clear well annotated networks. I got that just by googling I am sure you could find something.